# Set up Windows users that can only write to a specific folder

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I bought a new Windows 7 PC and I want to create three user accounts, which should have no permission to create anything in the C drive or on the desktop. The only place where they're allowed to write is a specific folder.

Here, they can create text or .doc files, and delete them, but they can't write to the others' folders by default. There should be an option though for the user to specify whether a file may be seen by others.

Is this possible?

Comment: You won't be able to limited the user's ability to write to their own profile.  More information about which version of Windows 7 is required to help.

Comment: windows 7 ultimate 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Make another account with admin ac password protected. Then in admin ac go to my computer right click on C drive or whatever you wanna restrict select `property` and got on `Security` tab select user ac name for example `GuestAC` other than admin and you can see a list of `Permission for GuestAC` select options as your need or you can go to advance settings also. Hope this is what you are in need.